# Как средствами Delphi узнать конец строки в многострочном поле.

Tags: delphi

Есть многострочное поле.... это поле всегда разное по значению. Из этого поля мне нужно взять только первую строчку. Вопрос в следующем. Как найти то место в тексте, где была нажата клавиша Enter? Т.е. как найти конец строки?

Comment: а у вас там в делфе есть метод типа, readLine()?

Answer (score 1):

`Memo1.Lines[0]`?

Answer (score 1):

> Как найти то место в тексте, где была нажата клавиша Enter?

В Delphi это будет подстрока `#13#10`.

Answer (score 0):

> Есть многострочное поле...

Я так понимаю, вы используете класс TMemo? У TMemo есть массив Lines, выдающий текст по строкам. Т.е. Memo.Lines[0] выдаст первую строку, Memo.Lines[1] - вторую и т.д. А клавиша Enter отмечается по-разному в разных операционных системах; для Windows это пара символов #13 и #10.

> мне нужно взять только первую строчку

Может быть, если остальные строчки вообще не будут использоваться, лучше использовать однострочное поле ввода TEdit?..